# Auto Move Google Form Response by ticking check box

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have google Form. User fills google form and a sheet with name "Form Response" is created to record user responses. I would like to use script to move data if I tick mark in W column, from "Form Response" sheet to "Verified Form Responses".

Link of the form Response Sheet is

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1LUUEZ7sSjBy-WWL3TZt8l6sqtrEBn3dZ03iRDTY1bF0/edit?usp=sharing

The script I am using is :

```
function onEdit(event) {
  // assumes source data in sheet named Needed
  // target sheet of move to named Acquired
  // test column with yes/no is col 23 or W
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var s = event.source.getActiveSheet();
  var r = event.source.getActiveRange();
  if(s.getName() == "Form responses 1" && r.getColumn() == 23 && r.getValue() == true) {
    var row = r.getRow();
    var numColumns = s.getLastColumn();
    var targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Verified Form Responses");
    var target = targetSheet.getRange(targetSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1);
    s.getRange(row, 1, 1, numColumns).copyTo(target);
    s.deleteRow(row);
  }
}
```

This code is not working. Please help.

Comment: What does it mean it is not working? do you see any errors in the execution page? do you see a behiavour that you don't expect? because what I see from the file you shared is that the code is working just fine.

Comment: The access to the linked spreadsheet is blocked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Issue:

For some reason the script is detecting content in all 1000 rows from `Verified Form Responses` sheet.

This can be checked by logging `targetSheet.getDataRange().getA1Notation()`: the logged notation is `A1:Z1000`, which means the script is seeing some content in row 1000.  It can also be checked by using [appendRow(rowContents)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#appendRow(Object)): the provided data is appended to row 1001, not to the first row with supposedly no content. Things like deleting all values from these rows don't cause any change (the script still considers these rows to have content).

I'm unsure what's the reason for that, since I don't see any array formula that might be messing with that. But every new row that is added to the sheet is interpreted as having content.

In any case, since it's detecting content in row 1000 (the last one in the sheet), `getLastRow() + 1` (that is, row 1001) is outside the dimensions of the sheet, so this error message appears:

> The coordinates of the target range are outside the dimensions of the sheet.

#### Solutions:

Fortunately, you have many options to solve this issue. Choose the one you prefer:

- Create a new target sheet, and send your data there instead of sending it to `Verified Form Responses`.
- Remove all the supposedly empty rows from `Verified Form Responses` (that is, `A42:Z1000`) and use `appendRow` instead of `copyTo` (formatting will not be copied):

```
var targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Verified Form Responses");
targetSheet.appendRow(s.getRange(row, 1, 1, numColumns).getValues()[0]);
```

- Find the actual first row without content by applying [getDataRange()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getdatarange) and filtering out rows for which all cells are empty (only works if there are no in-between empty rows):

```
var targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Verified Form Responses");
var realLastRow = targetSheet.getDataRange().getValues()
                             .filter(row => row.join('') != "").length;
var target = targetSheet.getRange(realLastRow + 1, 1);
s.getRange(row, 1, 1, numColumns).copyTo(target);
```

Comment: Thanks. This script is working with me but This sheet has been shared with other Team member with Editor right. When other team member click on the Check box, entry doesn't move to "Verified Form Responses" Sheet.

Comment: @Admin-RKPareekCo That's because your target sheet is protected and only you can edit it. Either unprotect the sheet (right-click on the sheet name, click `Protect sheet` and remove the protection), or install the onEdit sheet with your account so that the script executes under your authority.

Comment: I tried the same with removing protect sheet but it didn't work. I didn't understand the second option given by you i.e. install the onEdit sheet with your account. could you please let me know how to do this?

Comment: @Admin-RKPareekCo You didn't unprotect your sheet completely. Some ranges are still protected, columns E, F and L are protected: https://i.imgur.com/yrqloik.png. Remove those protections and it will work. If you prefer to install the onEdit trigger anyway, change the name of your function and follow [these steps](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable#managing_triggers_manually), while logged into your account (the one account for whom the protected sheet is completely unprotected). Let me know if those indications are enough or if you need more details.