# Automatically Move Google Form Response by Ticking Check Box

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, triggers, google-forms

I have 2 google Forms. User fills either of the google forms and it populates 2 "active" tabs within the same sheet to record user responses. I would like to use a script to move rows to a "completed" tab if I check a box in column 1.

This script works with non-form responses; but I'm not having no success with live form responses.

Thanks!

```
function onEdit(event) {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var s = event.source.getActiveSheet();
  var r = event.source.getActiveRange();

  if(s.getName() == "active" && r.getColumn() == 1 && r.getValue() == true) {
    var row = r.getRow();
    var numColumns = s.getLastColumn();
    var targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName("complete");
    var target = targetSheet.getRange(targetSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1);
    s.getRange(row, 1, 1, numColumns).moveTo(target);
    s.deleteRow(row);
  }
  
   if(s.getName() == "complete" && r.getColumn() == 1 && r.getValue() == false) {
    var row = r.getRow();
    var numColumns = s.getLastColumn();
    var targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName("active");
    var target = targetSheet.getRange(targetSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1);
    s.getRange(row, 1, 1, numColumns).moveTo(target);
    s.deleteRow(row);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply Rubén! So, I should replace the "onEdit" function with "onFormSubmit", and add a "onFormSubmit" trigger? Apologies, as I have little to no development experience.

Comment: The non-form responses and the form responses are on the same sheet, right? the checkbox is on the first column, right?

Answer (score 0):

The "problem" is that a onEdit simple triggers only is activated by user edits done using the Google Sheets UI. Instead of using a simple on edit trigger use a form submit trigger.

Add this function to the script bounded to the spreadsheet

```
function onFormSubmit(event){
   onEdit(event)
}
```

Create a form submit trigger on the script bounded to the spreadsheet.

In this case, the form submit function could call the onEdit function because the edit event object and the form submit object have the same properties used on the onEdit function, `souce`, `range`, and apparently the checkbox is set on the first column so `Range.getColumn() === 1` and `Range.getValue()` will return the same on both triggers. If the checkbox were on a different column, then some changes should be done or use two different functions.
Related

- [Auto Move Google Form Response by ticking check box](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64170478/1595451)

Reference

- https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply Rubén! So, I should replace the "onEdit" function with "onFormSubmit", and add a "onFormSubmit" trigger? Apologies, as I have little to no development experience.

Comment: You are welcome @Brian. If you need that the manually activation of the checkbox keep working, don't change the function name. The name of an installable trigger could be any valid function name, but avoid using reserved names like onEdit to keep easier to get info from the execution logs. `onFormSubmit` is OK, and yes create a installable trigger. You might have to do some slight changes. I will edit the answer to put these details.

Comment: @Brian answer edited.